# Use third party sdk classe in another third party sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, reflection, aar

I am developing android sdk (can be aar file or jar file)

In my sdk i want to use third party sdks that are referenced by the app itself

For example if the build.gradle of the app itself have this line:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0
```

I want to use the play-services-ads classes and methods in my own app without needing to  to reference it in my own aar

I thought of one way to do it - using reflection?

Can you suggest other ways?

Comment: What is your objective behind "without needing to to reference it in my own aar"? Are you just trying to avoid forcing developers to have that `play-services-ads` dependency?

Comment: @CommonsWare am trying to reduce aar/jar file size as much as possible and dont want to include other sdks dependencies in it

Answer (score 0):

I know of two choices: the safe way, and the simple way.

The safe way is to have two library modules. One contains most of your library code. The other one has dependencies on the first library and on the third-party library, and here is where your code that uses that third-party library lives. If the developer wants to use your code that uses the third-party library, they depend upon your second library; otherwise, they just use the first library.

The simple way is to use the `provided` scope:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    provided 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
}
```

This is a bit of a `build.gradle` from [a library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) that can add smarts to `HttpUrlConnection` and, optionally, to OkHttp. If the developer wants my OkHttp logic, they need to have their own `compile` directive for a compatible version of OkHttp. Just depending upon my library will not pull in OkHttp. Yet, at compile time, I can still reference OkHttp classes and stuff.

There are a couple of risks with `provided`:

- If the developer skips the `compile` directive for your `provided` dependency, then tries using your logic that needs the dependency, you crash at runtime, because the classes or methods that you need do not exist. You can attempt to use reflection to try to detect the library was compiled into the app (e.g., `Class.forName()` to see if something from OkHttp exists).
- You may have less control over what version of the dependency the app developer uses. With the first approach, you declare what version you support, and if the app developer tries overriding that with their own `compile` statement, they will get Gradle warnings and errors. I am not certain whether app developers get the same level of notification if their `compile` statement's version conflicts with your `provided` statement's version.

This library is the first time that I am trying `provided`. So far, I haven't had many complaints, but this library is fairly new.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand your objective quite well.

But if you don't reference the classes to be used, how could you compile your project?

Simply you should declare the play-services-ads dependencies in the final app project which uses your sdk aar.

Another trick is that you can use dependency "transitive" property in your sdk's build.gradle file, like the following:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```